# Is io.jsonwebtoken.JwtParser multi threaded?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Upon every request, I am executing the following (in package **io.jsonwebtoken**):

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);
```

Can I create and keep instance field and reuse it for all requests?

```
JwtParser jp = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret);
public Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        Jws<Claims> c = jp.parseClaimsJws(token);
        return c.getBody();
}
```

Would getAllClaimsFromToken method be **thread safe** if I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Jwts.parser()` is now deprecated. Please replace it with `Jwts.parserBuilder()` that returns a `JwtParserBuilder`. Instances of parsers returned from `Jwts.parserBuilder().....build()` are immutable (`ImmutableJwtParser`), which means that you can safely use them in a multithread environment.

```java
JwtParser immutableJwtParser = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secret).build();

public Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    Jws<Claims> c = immutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token);
    return c.getBody();
}
```